# what's the correct form of breaking a case with an if statement inside?

Tags: c

would you write it like this:

```
// This is just something a came up to explain my question

switch(a)
{
case 2:
    if(x >= 1)
    {
        dosomething();
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        dosomethingelse();
        break;
    }
default:
break;
}
```

or like this:

```
switch(a)
{
case 2:
    if(x >= 1)
    {
        dosomething();
    }
    else
    {
        dosomethingelse();
    }
    break;
default:
break;
}
```

Should the `break` be inside of the if/else statements or outside of these? is there a correct way or it doesn't matter?

Comment: I don't know if it's just a bad example but, in which case 'dosomethingelse()' would be executed?

Comment: yeah, the conditional should be with something like 'x'

Comment: Sorry, I just write the first thing that come up to my mind haha it was a bad example, but at least you understand what I was going for! Thanks for fixing it @KeithNicholas !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general second option will be preferred, some times that is all depends on your business test case. Switch case will be used if there is more than one if else ladder, to increase efficiency and readability of your code. Now to answer your question `break be inside of the if/else statements or outside?`

Scenario 1: If your have only if and else in your block, then break doesn't matter where it is. Anyhow only one bock will execute.

Scenario 2: You have some code to execute irrespective of condition inside the case block, then you have to put break at end.

Ex.

```
    switch(a)
        {
        case 2:
            if(a >= 1)
            {
                dosomething();
            }
            else
            {
                dosomethingelse();
            }
             doSomethingForthisCase();
            break;
        default:
          break;
      }
```

Many more scenario also you can think, like put break inside both else and last. In this case, if condition satisfies then `doSomethingForthisCase();` will execute, else only else block will execute, etc..

Comment: I know the thing of "is there more than one if else ladder" is the case to use switch, it was just some code/stuff that I write to make more clear my question, cuz english is not my mother tongue so it was more easy for me to write this question... But, yeah, man, thanks for answering this question that I had before all of you help me out! :) have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

I would go for the second option, tends to be a lot clearer that the case statement does have a break.

If you have the break in the if, usually it's to short circuit the case statement so it doesn't keep executing.  Though, be careful with short circuiting, as it can make things more confusing / error prone, and often is a symptom of doing too much in the switch.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, but it's better to do it like the second one, as you should do the break right after each case statement. Also it tends to have a more readable and manageable code, as you may change the `if` sections later and thus lose the `break`s.

So you can do it just like this:

```
switch(a){

    case 1:

       if( a > b ){
       // do something
       }else{
       //do some other thing
       }

       break;

    case 2:

       if( a > c ){
       // do something
       }else{
       //do some other thing
       }

       break;

    default

       break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the above answers, second option would be preferable as the repeating breaks could be avoided. However, I would also like to suggest that break for default is not necessary. As default tends to be be the last option executed.

Comment: I'd tend to put it in, for pretty much the same reasons discussed here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/201777/break-on-default-case-in-switch

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you want 1 exit point, so an if/else chain of equal weight should have the break at the bottom.

```
if(a >= 1)
{
    dosomething();
}
else
{
    dosomethingelse();
}
break;
```

A common exception is pretesting for error conditions and breaking out before performing the operation.

```
if(a < 1)
{
    handle_error();
    break;
}

dosomething();
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of them would work, but definetely the second option is the way to do it. The first one it breaks a logic structure, and that's never a good practice.